# @NamedQuery cachable result alternative

Tags: performance, jpa, java-ee-6, ejb-3.1, glassfish-4

I'm using `@NamedQuery` to get some results from my DataBase. After manipulating it for a while, I understood that the `@NamedQuery` is requested once the application is deployed & stored it in the cache for more performance.

So, I'm searching for a way(kind of query) that get always the information from database when the request is made, so I can get always updated data ?
And if there is a way to do such a thing, what is its performance ?

Comment: a named query is COMPILED once (into SQL). It should always be executed unless you have turned on some JPA provider-specific query RESULTS caching. But you don't define what you have enabled

Comment: @DN1 where can I find such a configuration ? Because I didn't do any configuration !

Comment: You defined an EMF, so you did "some" configuration. You have a LOG so you can see what SQL is invoked.

Comment: @DN1 Yes Yes, you're right, you oriented me to target the right issue, thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As outlined already in the comments, you have misunderstanding of the NamedQuery. Not the result is stored in cache, but the query SQL is.

Nevertheless sometimes the EntityManager caches some things and I guess you need a solution for that....

If you are working with Query objects (e.g. EntityManager.createNamedQuery("nameOfYourQuery")) and EclipseLink then you can do the following:

```
Query query = EntityManager.createNamedQuery("nameOfYourQuery");
query.setHint(QueryHints.REFRESH, HintValues.TRUE);
query.getResultList();
```

You can also setup query hints directly in the NamedQuery like this:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "something", query = "SELECT n FROM something",
 hints=@QueryHint(name=QueryHints.REFRESH, value=HintValues.TRUE))
```

Another way with query hints would be this one:

```
query.setHint(QueryHints.CACHE_USAGE, CacheUsage.DoNotCheckCache);
```

For a list of possible query hints, have a look at [the EclipseLink docs](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/Query_Hints).

If you want to completely deactivate database result caching you can also try the following in your `persistence.xml`:

```
<property name="eclipselink.query-results-cache" value="false"/>
```

Comment: Thank you this is what I looked for, I discussed the issue with an experienced colleague & he gives me the same explanation, but without technical details, once again thanks !